# Reversing the order of default arguments in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, default, default-value

I have the following recursive `compose` function:

```js
const compose = (f, n = 1) => n > 1 ?
    compose(compose(f), n - 1) :
    g => x => f(g(x));

const length = a => a.length;

const filter = p => a => a.filter(p);

const countWhere = compose(length, 2)(filter);

const odd = n => n % 2 === 1;

console.log(countWhere(odd)([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])); // 5
```

Now, what I'd like to do is flip the arguments of `compose` so that the default argument is first:

```js
const compose = (n = 1, f) => n > 1 ? // wishful thinking
    compose(n - 1, compose(f)) : // compose(f) is the same as compose(1, f)
    g => x => f(g(x));

const length = a => a.length;

const filter = p => a => a.filter(p);

const countWhere = compose(2, length)(filter); // I want to call it like this

const odd = n => n % 2 === 1;

console.log(countWhere(odd)([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])); // 5
```

What's the most elegant way to write such functions where the default arguments come first?

---

**Edit:** I actually want to create the [`map`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#functor) and [`ap`](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply) methods of functions of various arities, so that I can write:

```js
const length = a => a.length;

const filter = p => a => a.filter(p);

const countWhere = length.map(2, filter); // length <$> filter

const pair = x => y => [x, y];

const add = x => y => x + y;

const mul = x => y => x * y;

const addAndMul = pair.map(2, add).ap(2, mul); // (,) <$> (+) <*> (*)
```

Hence, I'd rather not curry the methods as Bergi suggested in his answer.

For more information, read: [Is implicit wrapping and unwrapping of newtypes in Haskell a sound idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51648855/is-implicit-wrapping-and-unwrapping-of-newtypes-in-haskell-a-sound-idea)

Comment: `(...args) => f(...args.reverse())` maybe ... :)

Comment: @JonasW. Where are the default arguments?

Comment: Right, this is actually more tricky than I thought ...

Comment: Some linters warn when default arguments are specified before parameters without defaults. This makes sense as it’s impossible to call such a function without specifying the leading arguments - you _could_ write `compose(undefined, f)` but of course that’s worse than `compose(1, f)`, imo

Comment: @user633183 I guess it's best to stick the default arguments at the end then. It just looks better when it's in the beginning though.

Comment: Your argument is for "looking better" when I find the entirety of your code difficult to comprehend.  Chained currying :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the most elegant way to write such functions where the default arguments come first?

Using only default initialisers requires some arcane hackery:

```js
function demo(n, f = [n, n = 1][0]) {
    console.log(n, f);
}
demo(2, "f"); // 2 f
demo("g"); // 1 g
console.log(demo.length) // 1
```

The most straightforward way would be destructuring with a conditional operator:

```js
function demo(...args) {
    const [n, f] = args.length < 2 ? [1, ...args] : args;
    console.log(n, f);
}
demo(2, "f"); // 2 f
demo("g"); // 1 g
console.log(demo.length) // 0
```

More in the spirit of "reversing the order of arguments" might be doing that literally:

```js
function demo(...args) {
    const [f, n = 1] = args.reverse();
    console.log(n, f);
}
demo(2, "f"); // 2 f
demo("g"); // 1 g
console.log(demo.length) // 0
```

The latter two attempts have the drawback of requiring an extra declaration (preventing us from using concise arrow functions) and also don't reflect the actual number or required parameters in the `.length`.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to just not overload your functions or use default parameters:

```
const compose = n => f => n > 1
  ? compose(n - 1)(composeOne(f))
  : g => x => f(g(x));
const composeOne = compose(1);
```

In this case you could probably also just inline it, as it seems `composeOne` wouldn't be called anywhere else:

```
const compose = n => f => n > 1
  ? compose(n - 1)(compose(1)(f))
  : g => x => f(g(x));
```

Or even not do a recursive call at all, but always create the `g => x => …` lambda and transform it conditionally:

```
const compose = n => f => {
  const l = g => x => f(g(x));
  return n > 1 ? compose(n - 1)(l) : l;
};
// same without temporary variables:
const id = x => x;
const compose = n => f => (n > 1 ? compose(n-1) : id)(g => x => f(g(x)))
```

Comment: That definitely seems to be more in the spirit of functional programming. However, I have a different requirement. I'll edit my question to reflect that. Anyway, +1 for the one liner.